# Synaptics touchpad after upgrade to kubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: touchpad, dell, synaptics

I upgraded to kubuntu 16.04 about half a year ago and still couldn't get my touchpad working. It worked immediatly after the upgrade but stopped soon (can't remember it is was after the first reboot, very likely).

Following this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection#generalinfo I assumed it's related to the linux kernel since it isn't listed neither by `xinput` nor by `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`. 
Thus I opened a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1631753)
but updating to kernel v4.8 didn't fix it neither.

Using a live boot the touchpad works.

`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed.

I further tried different kernel options as they seemed to solve it for other users (can't post links because I don't have enough reputation).

System settings > Input devices > Touchpad shows "Synaptics backend not found"

Laptop model: Dell XPS 13
Touchpad manufacturer: Synaptics

Does anyone have an idea to fix this?